# Closure compiler - Can I compile files but not remove comments and whitespace?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a couple of JavaScript source files that I'm compiling with Google's Closure compiler. I'd like to compile a version that simply concatenates the files together and doesn't remove whitespace or comments. This is so I can generate a version that's easy to debug.

Is there a way to compile, but retain whitespace and comments?

Comment: From the documentation, it doesn't seem so. Maybe just use `cat` instead? Also take a look at https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq#sourcemaps.

Comment: I don't think you can preserve comments and whitespace, but you can pretty print the result.

Comment: @Thomas is 'cat' a command-line command?

Comment: Yep, in everything but Windows at least :)

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"? Do you want advanced compilation while preserving comments? That doesn't seem likely since the code is heavily altered. And which comments do you want to keep? Do you want all the annotations, or other?

Comment: @Thomas Haha, I found that out. Luckily, there's a similar command called 'type' in Windows

Comment: @squint I guess 'compile' is not the right word in this case. It should really be 'concatenate'. In any case, Thomas's comments have  led me to the right answer